PHP Fatal error: Class 'Laravel\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
I'm new to Laravel and I'm unsure about the cause of this error:

Class 'Laravel\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Controllers' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\local\app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\AuthController.php on line 24.

I've verified that the namespaces are correct. I'm using localhost to run the app, which already exists on the server, and I want to run it locally.
Here's AuthController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Category;
use App\Package;
use App\Role;
use App\Skill;
use App\SubscriptionsUser;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Validator;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = array();

    }

    // Other content of the code

}

And Controller.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}


Do you have dependencies installed locally (is there a vendor directory at the root of your app) ?

Yes there is a vendor directory in the root of my app

Okay. I don't know much about Laravel but something looks wrong to me here: the error message in your question title gives a different namespace from your question body. Anyways, I don't see any use for a Laravel top-level namespace.

I really don't have any idea

could you edit the post and specify  what you did for run the app locally? did you just  copy and paste the project on localhost? you need to set document_root to the correct "laravel_app_public_path", and( if you have configured  php , composer and all other stuff properly)  just  run a php artisan clear:cache (if you are using laravel 7)
